# I am trying to set up a counter within classes and it dosent work. Also not sure the random part isnt working right.

Tags: c#, class, random

I am new to c# and specifically classes.   I am trying to have multiple dice roll and for the top line of dice be the players dice and the bottom the computer dice.  I set up a counter to count each dice roll and tell the user.  So far it gives me 0.

Also the dice rolls are meant to be random but I am not sure they are completly random.

Any help would be great.  Thank you.

```
    namespace Week_6._3
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
            public void Squares(int x, int y)
            {
                int width = this.pictureBox1.Width;
                int sizeDice = width/ 7;

                Graphics paper = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
                SolidBrush brushWhite = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                Pen penBlack = new Pen(Color.Black);

                paper.FillRectangle(brushWhite, x, y, sizeDice, sizeDice);
                paper.DrawRectangle(penBlack, x, y, sizeDice, sizeDice);
            }
            public void Circles(int x, int y, int counter)
            {
                SolidBrush blackbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                Graphics paper = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
                int width = this.pictureBox1.Width;
                int length = this.pictureBox1.Height;
                int sizeDice = width / 7;
                int sizeCircle = sizeDice/7;
                int firstRowCircles =  sizeCircle;
                int secondRowCircles = sizeCircle * 3;
                int thirdRowCircles = sizeCircle * 5;

                Random  random = new Random();
                int num = random.Next(1,6);

                if (num == 1)
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + secondRowCircles, y + secondRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                }
                else if (num == 2)
                {
                    counter = counter + 2;
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + firstRowCircles, y +   firstRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + thirdRowCircles, y + thirdRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                }
                else if (num == 3)
                {
                    counter = counter + 3;
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + firstRowCircles, y + firstRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + secondRowCircles, y + secondRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + thirdRowCircles, y + thirdRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                }
                else if (num == 4)
                {
                    counter = counter + 4;
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + firstRowCircles, y + firstRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + firstRowCircles, y + thirdRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + thirdRowCircles, y + firstRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + thirdRowCircles, y + thirdRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                }
                else if (num == 5)
                {
                    counter = counter + 5;
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + firstRowCircles, y + firstRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + firstRowCircles, y + thirdRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + thirdRowCircles, y + firstRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + thirdRowCircles, y + thirdRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + secondRowCircles, y + secondRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                }
                else if (num == 6)
                {
                    counter = counter + 6;
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + firstRowCircles, y + firstRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + firstRowCircles, y + secondRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + firstRowCircles, y + thirdRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + thirdRowCircles, y + firstRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + thirdRowCircles, y + secondRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                    paper.FillEllipse(blackbrush, x + thirdRowCircles, y + thirdRowCircles, sizeCircle, sizeCircle);
                }

            }
            private void buttonRollDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int width = this.pictureBox1.Width;
                int length = this.pictureBox1.Height;
                int widthShift = width / 7;
                int middleWidth = widthShift * 3;
                int rightWidth = widthShift * 5;
                int allTopDiceLength = length / 8;
                int allBottomDiceLength = allTopDiceLength + (length / 2);

                int playerCounter = 0;
                int computerCounter = 0;

                //Top Left Square
                Squares(widthShift, allTopDiceLength);
                Circles(widthShift, allTopDiceLength, playerCounter);

                //Bottom Left Square
                Squares(widthShift, allBottomDiceLength);
                Circles(widthShift, allBottomDiceLength, computerCounter);

                //Top Middle Square
                Squares(middleWidth, allTopDiceLength);
                Circles(middleWidth, allTopDiceLength, playerCounter);

                //Bottom Middle Square
                Squares(middleWidth, allBottomDiceLength);
                Circles(middleWidth, allBottomDiceLength, computerCounter);

                //Top Right Square
                Squares(rightWidth, allTopDiceLength);
                Circles(rightWidth, allTopDiceLength, playerCounter);

                //Bottom Middle Square
                Squares(rightWidth, allBottomDiceLength);
                Circles(rightWidth, allBottomDiceLength, computerCounter);

                labelPlayerRolls.Text = Convert.ToString(playerCounter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're modifying an argument of the function, which doesn't do anything substantial. You have `public void Circles(int x, int y, int counter)` and then do things like `counter = counter + 1;`, but you're only modifying a copy of that thing. Either access a static field in some class or use the `ref` keyword to pass by reference. Everytime in `buttonRollDice_Click` the `playerCounter` resets to zero and isn't modifyed after a `Squares()` or `Circles()` call.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.

Comment: Move `Random` variable outside of your function.

Answer (score 1):

Code is actually updating function argument, so you will not see updated value in caller method/function as it is passed by value *not* reference.

You have couple of options to fix this problem.

**Option 1:**

You could modify `circle` method definition to have return value.

```
public int Circles(int x, int y, int counter)
{
     ...
     return counter
}
```

**Option 2:**

Pass `counter` as reference argument.

```
public void Circles(int x, int y, ref int counter)
{
     ...         
}
```

**Option 3:**

Define instance variable and update the value as required(no need to pass argument, directly use instance variable).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
      public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private int counter;

      ....

      public void Circles(int x, int y)
      {
           ...         
      }

}
```